# Returning the element number of the longest string in an array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm trying to get the longest method to take the user-inputted array of strings, then return the element number of the longest string in that array.  I got it to the point where I was able to return the number of chars in the longest string, but I don't believe that will work for what I need.  My problem is that I keep getting incompatible type errors when trying to figure this out.  I don't understand the whole data type thing with strings yet.  It's confusing me how I go about return a number of the array yet the array is of strings.   The main method is fine, I got stuck on the ???? part.

```
public static void main(String [] args) 
{
    Scanner inp = new Scanner( System.in );
    String [] responseArr= new String[4];

    for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
     System.out.println("Enter string "+(i+1));
     responseArr[i] = inp.nextLine();
    }
    int highest=longestS(responseArr);
}

public static int longestS(String[] values)
{    
    int largest=0

    for( int i = 1; i < values.length; i++ )
    {
        if ( ?????          )

    }
    return largest; 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your code to improve the formatting (tabbing, etc) - this will increase the number of (good) answers you get.

Comment: When I was an undergraduate, the staff "programming advisers" would **refuse** to offer **any** help unless the code was properly formatted.  IMO, "I'm new to this site" is not a valid excuse either.

Comment: What if the array of strings is
{ "this" , 'list" , "same" , 'size" , "four" }? What index should your method return?

Answer (score 3):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
    {
        if (values[i].length() > largest)
        {
            largest = values[i].length();
            index = i;
        }
    }
    return index;
```

Note: initialize the int `i` with 0 - array index is 0-based.

Back in your `main`, you could then do `System.out.println("Longest: " + responseArr[highest]);` etc.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I'd write it:

```
public static int findIndexOfLongestString(String[] values)
{     
   int index = -1;

   if ((values != null) && (values.length > 0))
   {
       index = 0;
       String longest = values[0];
       for (int i = 1; i < values.length; ++i)
       {
          if (values[i].length() > longest.length())
          {
             longest = values[i];
             index = i;
          }
       }
   }

   return index;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will want to store two things in your `longestS` method: the largest length so far, and the array index of the largest length. Also keep in mind that array indices start at 0 in Java. A for loop initialised with `int i = 1` is actually going to start at the second index.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
public class JavaApplication3
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] big={"one","two","three"};
        String bigstring=null;
        int maxlength=0;
        for(String max:big)
        {
            if(maxlength<max.length())
            {
                maxlength=max.length();
                bigstring=max;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(bigstring);
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not return the index in the array.